# Javascript Form Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that a user would fill, I would like to submit those answers to variables in javascript and then call a function to display all the data entered into the form on a different page. For example the form is on 1.html, the user presses the submit button, is redirected to 2.html and the submitted information is shown here. Here is my form:

```
<form action="addaddresspage3.html" method="post" id="form" class="form">
    <div id="form1">

    <div class="row form-row form-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-wrapper">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-content">
                        <legend class="hd-default">Billing Address</legend>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                <label for="first-name">First Name(s)*:</label> 
                                <input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name(s)" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                <label for="password">Surname*:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                    <label>Country of Home Address</label>
                                    <select name="title" id="addresslist" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="1">Select Address</option>
                                        <option value="1">United Kingdom</option>
                                        <option value="2">Saudi Arabia</option>
                                        <option value="3">Iran</option>
                                        <option value="4">Nigeria</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">


                                <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">House number and street:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="street_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="autocomplete"  size="54" maxlength="120" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing address." onFocus="geolocate()" placeholder="Please enter your house number and street">


                                    <p>

                                        <label for="city_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Town:</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="city_#Add#" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" required="yes" id="locality" size="30"  maxlength="50" message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing city." value="">       

                                    </p>

                                    <label for="street_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Postcode:</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="postal_#Add#" required="yes" id="postal_code" size="8" maxlength="12"  message="Please enter owner #Peoplecount#'s mailing zip code." value="">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
  </div>

  </div>
   <input type="submit" id="continue" disabled="disabled" value="Add Address"/>
   </div>
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript that you've written?  Note that *variables* won't carry a value to the next page, but you can store the values in perhaps local storage, or maybe include them in the query string for the next page.

Comment: So is there no way to pass variables from page to page?

Comment: You can store or submit *values* just as I described.  But a "variable", as an in-memory concept, won't be available outside the scope of that variable's lifespan.  This is true in every programming language.

Comment: This is only needed for a prototype so a short lifespan is fine @David

Comment: I have no idea what you meant by that reply.  And I'm pretty sure neither did you.

Comment: I knew exactly what I meant by that @David

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate then?  Because it didn't make much sense in the context of this question.

Comment: "You can store or submit values just as I described. But a "variable", as an in-memory concept, won't be available outside the scope of that variable's lifespan. This is true in every programming language." Having it available only in the variable's lifespan is fine, it only needs to be in-memory

Comment: That's different from what was being asked in the question.  If you want the values to persist from one page to another, then you're going to have to persist them somewhere.  If, on the other hand, you only want the values to be stored in in-memory variables, then you're going to have to remain on the same page and perform your tasks there.  You should definitely more concretely define the functionality you're looking to implement before you attempt to implement it.

Comment: I stated in the question that it needs to go from page to page...@David

Comment: Then persist the values somewhere.  Local storage is a good option, query string values being passed to the next page is a usable alternative.  (Though I'd recommend the former.)  Have you tried?  In what way did the attempt not succeed?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the two are on the same domain you can set the data to cookies and repopulate them on the next page..

**Page1**

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
    var cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + ";";
    document.cookie = cookie;
}

$("#form1").submit(function(){
    setCookie("input1", $("#input1").val()); // do this for all inputs
});
```

Page2

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var chunks = document.cookie.split(";");
    for(var i=chunks.length; i--;){
        if(chunks[i].trim().split("=")[0].trim() == name){
            return chunks[i].trim().split("=")[1].trim();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input1").val(getCookie("iunput1")); // do the same for the other inputs
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have copied the whole of the page 2, after editing the fields. But the page is just blank, do I need to display the values such as an alert?

Comment: Yeah I have, thats what I meant when I said 'editing the fields'. The element id's are correct, just nothing is shown. I dont think the elements are being disppalyed

Comment: if you have firefox you can check the cookies in the cookies tab in the console, i'm sure it's there for chome too but idk..

Comment: php is the easiest way to go.. are you working on a server?

Comment: Also, my answer uses jQuery, you had jQuery tagged, so make sure you have jQuery included in your page or my answer won't work.

Comment: Yeah I have jQuery included. I know it would be easier with PHP but i'm not working on a server and want to try with no server scripting

Comment: then maybe don't tag php in your question :)\

Comment: Just to get more views :)

Answer (score 0):

Either use a service to store your value or web storage like localStorage pr sessionStorage to save you values from the form on page1.html and fetch them on form2.html to use

Comment: Yes. If you provide the piece of JS code your sample html files, we may use  web storage to do that

Comment: I don't have any JS, just that form

Answer (score 0):

You can persist values using [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).  For example, to write a value to storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('myValue', someVariable);
```

Then, on the next page, fetch that value:

```
var someVariable = localStorage.getItem('myValue');
```

And when you're done with the value in storage, be sure to remove it:

```
localStorage.removeItem('myValue');
```